# PHPUnit test - Failed asserting that actual size 11935 matches expected size 3

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, tdd, assertions

I'm brand new to phpunit and attempting to write a test that asserts that three notes were created, but I'm getting all of the notes from the DB.

```
    /** @test */
    public function it_gets_notes()
    {
        $address = Address::first();
        $notes = factory(AddressNote::class, 3)->create(['address_id' 
        => $address->id]);
        $found = $this->notesClass->getData(['address_id' => $address-
        >id]);
        $this->assertCount(3, $found);
    }
}
```

The Address and AddressNote models are working properly. I think I'm most confused about the `getData` method, which I know I need for my code coverage. Anyone see what I'm missing that would generate the error in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check the *difference* after running your `create` method, then save `$found` before and after adding them, and the subtraction will be your number:

```
public function it_gets_notes()
{
    $address = Address::first();
    $found = $this->notesClass->getData(['address_id' => $address->id]);
    $notes = factory(AddressNote::class, 3)->create(['address_id' => $address->id]);
    $foundAfter = $this->notesClass->getData(['address_id' => $address->id]);
    $difference = count($foundAfter) - count($found);
    $this->assertEquals(3, $difference);
}
```

Note that you need to use `assertEquals()` with 3 and the difference now instead of `assertCount()`, since you're comparing numbers.

Comment: That gives me `Error: Unsupported operand types` for the subtraction :/

Comment: Sorry, give it a try now.

Comment: Ah, but now I'm getting "PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #2 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertCount() must be a countable or traversable", though when I dd($difference); it's 3. You'd think it'd pass...

Comment: So use `$this->assertEquals(count($foundAfter), count($found));` :).

Comment: That gave me: "Failed asserting that 11932 matches expected 11935." `$this->assertEquals(3, $difference);` passes though. Thanks!!!

Comment: Duh, right! Edited the answer to reflect that. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the whole your story, but I assume that your first mistake was that you did not create a testing database.
So, that would be the first step - in addition to your databaseName (whatever the name) create a databaseName_test.
There are some other steps to do - in your ,env file change the name of the databaseName to databaseName_testing - but only while you're doing your testing (and then immediately rollback to your original databaseName).
Yet, the problem can still persist (PHP Unit is not a perfect tool, just like PHP), and here is the hack that can help.
Instead of:

```
    $this->assertEquals(3, $difference);
```

write:

```
    $this->assertEquals(11935, $difference); //the number is specific for your case
```

Yep, it's stupid, but it should work...